# Convert all characters to HTML entities

Tags: java, string

I want to "protect" email addresses so I want to convert **someone@somewhere.any** to

```
&#115;&#111;&#109;&#101;&#111;&#110;&#101;&#64;&#115;&#111;&#109;&#101;&#119;&#104;&#101;&#114;&#101;&#46;&#97;&#110;&#121;
```

What can I use in java to do this?

Comment: Protect them for what purpose?

Comment: The only thing this would do is make the address hard to read in the source for a human being. This is in no way protection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming well behave character sets.

```
    String email = "someone@somewhere.any";
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(email.length() * 6);
    for (char c : email.toCharArray()) {
        buffer.append("&#").append((int) c).append(';');
    }
    System.out.println(buffer);
```

Comment: I want to nitpick on this because surrogate pairs are treated incorrectly and technically because internationalised domains do exist, you could conceivably have one even in an email address. On the other hand, most web forms where people can type in an email address prohibit them, so...

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scanner to scan through each character and replace them with a specific value.
You would use the following:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(someone@somewhere.any);
char c = reader.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
//Replace that character with the desired one.
```